# Odoo8 | my custom website theme isn't loading its GUI

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-website

I'm trying to make a new theme for odoo-8 website.. By following these steps in [odoo-theme-tutorial](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/themes.html) . when went through step of Extend the default header I didn't get the expected output. All I get is a page og text without applying neither the CSS effect nor the JS. I don't know what am I missing.. any help will be appreciated.
Here's my code:

in openerp file:

```
{
    # Theme information
    'name': "theme_businesscasual",

    'description': """
    """,

    'category': 'Theme',

    'version': '1.0',

    'depends': ['website', 'website_less'],

    # templates

    'data': [
        'views/layout.xml',
    ],

    'application': True
}
```

in layout.xml file:

```
<!-- Customize header  -->

<template id="custom_header" inherit_id="website.layout" name="Custom Header">

  <!-- Assign an id  -->

  <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header" position="attributes">

    <attribute name="id">my_header</attribute>

  </xpath>

  <!-- Add an element after the top menu  -->

  <xpath expr="//div[@id='wrapwrap']/header/div" position="after">

    <div class="container">

      <div class="alert alert-info mt16" role="alert">

        <strong>Welcome</strong> to our website!

      </div>

    </div>

  </xpath>

</template>
```

Here's a screenshot of what I get:
[image]

Comment: looks like you strip down css. Are there any errors in js console?